# Full address from OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, open-source-routing-machine

I've built a routing application in C# that brings back a `route` object, with a series of `steps`, each of which has a `name` tag such as `"Brooke Street (M50)"` and nothing more.

This application has been built with an [OSRM](http://map.project-osrm.org/) backend, using data from `Geofabrik`. When I run a query in `map.project-OSRM.org`, I'm able to see the full address (street, county, country, postcode). When I run the same query on my local copy of OSRM, I'm only able to retrieve the street name.

Is anybody able to tell me where I can either download the additional data, or how to get access to it? I'm in need of reverse geocoding > full address functionality, which isn't fully possible with what I have access to at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For obtaining the full address you have to use a geocoder such as [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). There are other [geocoders for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) available, too.

Also see [your very similar question at help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/51423/reverse-geocode-to-full-address).